# Can applications access Azure Cosmos using AD authentication instead of connection string key

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-cosmosdb

Is it possible for applications to connect with azure ad authentication instead of connection string key.

Answer (score 0):

As of today, the answer is no. You would need account name/key to connect an application to Cosmos DB. Azure AD based authentication is not supported as of today.

Answer (score 0):

Currently it is supporting two approaches:

1. Master Key based
2. Resource token based

Currently we can't do the Azure AD based authentication.